process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE is undefined
I want to know the ID of the instance of the script, but the enviroment variable process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE is undefined (same with process.env.INSTANCE_ID)
My code :
(async () => {


    console.log("Instance ID = " + process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE);

    process.exit();


})();

Any idea? Do I need to do somehting else to fetch is?
I start my script with :
pm2 start script.js -i 3 --no-autorestart -- myarg


nicolas@localhost:~/Desktop/projets-web/demarchage$ pm2 -v
5.4.2

Thanks

first of all, check if there are 3 elements there:
1 - "dotenv" dependency installed
2 - .env configuration file in the project root
3 - if the .env file has this variable NODE_APP_INSTANCE
From the way the project came already instantiated, the problem is probably the absence of the .env file

You are right, I forgot to npm install dotenv . thanks

If your node version is >20.6, node has an inbuilt utility to read environment variables
https://philna.sh/blog/2023/09/05/nodejs-supports-dotenv/
